# Overriding and overhiding

Tags: java, overriding, abstract

Can someone please explain me why below code is not valid and is giving me the error.

```
/* Java program to show that if static methods are redefined by 
   a derived class, then it is not overriding but hidding. */

// Superclass 
class Base { 

    // Static method in base class which will be hidden in subclass  
    public static void display() { 
        System.out.println("Static or class method from Base"); 
    } 

     // Non-static method which will be overridden in derived class  
     public void print()  { 
         System.out.println("Non-static or Instance method from Base"); 
    } 
} 

// Subclass 
class Derived extends Base { 

    // Static is removed here (Causes Compiler Error)  
    public void display() { 
        System.out.println("Non-static method from Derived"); 
    } 

    // Static is added here (Causes Compiler Error)  
    public static void print() { 
        System.out.println("Static method from Derived"); 
   } 

}
```

Comment: You can't override a static method with a non-static method, and vice versa.

Comment: Yes ,But can you please explain the reason behind it.Why we can't override a static method with a non-static method, and vice versa

Comment: Because it doesn't make sense. Static and instance methods are very different beasts, the former does not belong to instances of the class, the latter does; the former is not invoked polymorphically, the latter is; etc.

Answer (score 3):

It's an error simply because it's defined not to be allowed.

You can't [override a static method with an instance method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1):

> (Of an instance method:) It is a compile-time error if the overridden method, `mA`, is a static method.

or [hide an instance method with a static method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.2):

> It is a compile-time error if a static method hides an instance method.